# Show that the set of matrices is orthonormal with respect to Frobenius inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having difficulty discovering the method to determine if a set of matrices is orthonormal. I have several of these questions but the given answer is always "its easy to see the set is orthonormal" But it does not indicate how to see it.

For example:

$$P = \left\{\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}i&i\\1&1\end{pmatrix}, \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\i&-i\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

Has inner product space over $\mathbb{C}$ with respect to Frobenius inner product.

Comment: If i perform the Frobenius inner product, it gives zero as the answer. i -i+i-i=0. So i have that it is orthogonal. Is this correct so far?

Comment: Yes. Now Frobenius-multiply each by itself. and see if you get $1$.

Comment: Okay great. Solved. What do I do now, answer my own question or leave it as is? Mods?